# Can Below Script take where clause from Spread sheet A@ cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a JavaScript I using in Google Apps Script (spreadhseet). When I run the code, it takes certain data from MySQL tables.

I need to know, can I add a `WHERE` clause in that SQL which takes the string from the Spreadsheet and run.

Now I specify the `WHERE` clause manually in code. I need that `WHERE` clause string from the Spreadsheet cell and run and give me a result.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**:

Absolutely! You can build the where clause in Apps Script dynamically by taking data from a bound sheet.

Example:

If, for example, the data you want to take is in column B:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<your-spreadsheet-id'>);
var condition = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange('B1').getValue();
var value = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange('B2').getValue();

var sqlClause = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE " + condition + " = " + value;
```

References:

- [w3Schools - SQL `WHERE` Clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)
- [Google Apps Script - Class `SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)